# Rails Routing Help - Edit/Show have :id/:action, but delete has :action/:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

my routes.rb

```
root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
resources :articles
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

my articles_controller.rb

```
def delete
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  article = Article.find(params[:id])
  article.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Article destroyed successfully."
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end
```

my delete.html.rb

```
<h2>Delete Article</h2>

<div class="subjects delete">
<h2>Delete Subject</h2>

<%= form_for(:article, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @article.id}) do |f| %>
<p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>
<p><%= @article.title %></p>

  <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("Delete Article") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when i click edit article its redirecting to
`http://localhost:3000/articles/7/edit`

Show is redirecting to `localhost:3000/articles/7`

Where as delete is redirecting to `localhost:3000/articles/delete/8`
and when clicking delete button it says `The action '8' could not be found for ArticlesController`

Why i dont get redirected to `localhost:3000/articles/8/delete`

i changed routes.rb to

```
match ':controller(/:id(/:action))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

in this delete works but edit doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be best using the [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) directive for the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles #-> url.com/articles/:id/destroy
resources :pages, only: [], path: "" do
   get :about, on: :collection #-> url.com/about
end
root 'pages#home'
```

The above will provide the correct *routes*.

Your problem is you're submitting a *form* to try and change the value. This will not work; you'll need:

```
#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
<%= button_to "Delete", article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

This will call your `posts#destroy` controller & fire your code (which seems okay).

Comment: Thanks A Lot, it Worked :)

Comment: Good job! You should accept the answer so future readers know it works